# How to import multiple variables in a single string

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a rather simple task that i am stumped on, i am making random integer variables but i do not know how to print them inside a string, code is below

```
def mastermind():
    import random
    num1 = randint(0,9)
    num2 = randint(0,9)
    num3 = randint(0,9)
    num4 = randint(0,9)

    print("The numbers are  " num1, num2, num3, num 4 " .")

mastermind():
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

```
print("The numbers are: {} {} {} {}.".format(num1, num2, num3, num 4))
```

Comment: Is there meant to be a double bracket at the end? and if so why is it there

Comment: One closing bracket for print statement and another closing for format function

Comment: Thanks i understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` instead of `,` and cast the numbers to string

```
print("The numbers are  " + str(num1) + str(num2) + str(num3) + str(num4)+ " .")
```

Comment: Thanks! Im still really new to python and its very useful for people to help me

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

You can place a placeholder string and replace it with variables.

```
def mastermind():
     import random
     num1 = random.randint(0,9)
     num2 = random.randint(0,9)
     num3 = random.randint(0,9)
     num4 = random.randint(0,9)

     print("The numbers are %s %s %s %s. " %(num1, num2, num3, num4))

 mastermind()
```

You can convert `int` to string and concatenate strings.

```
def mastermind():
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(0,9)
    num2 = random.randint(0,9)
    num3 = random.randint(0,9)
    num4 = random.randint(0,9)

    print("The numbers are " + str(num1) + " " +  str(num2) + " " + str(num3) + " " + str(num4) + ".")
```

You can also use `format`.

```
def mastermind():
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(0,9)
    num2 = random.randint(0,9)
    num3 = random.randint(0,9)
    num4 = random.randint(0,9)    

    print("The numbers are {} {} {} {}".format(num1, num2, num3, num4))

mastermind()
```